# Check if product exists in Magento using REST API

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Is there a way to check if product exists in Magento before I try to add new one.
My solution will always get exception if product with wanted Id is not in Magento DB.

```
function isProductInDatabase($setup, $product){
  try
     {
        $url = "{$setup['apiUrl']}/products/1";
        $oauthClient = $setup['oauthClient'];
        $postType = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET;
        $header = $setup['headers'];
        $setup['oauthClient']->fetch($url, array(), $postType, $header);
     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {
        //throw new Exception( 'Error while loading product', 0, $e);
        return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Product exists means? Based on which unique condition are checking?

Comment: For example if i have product, it is ok (no Exception), but if i don't have product it will throw exception. Is there better way to do this instead to catch exception.